# Store 2-legged one-time password's key securely

Tags: encryption, password-management, one-time-password, algorithm

I have a system with a OTP authentication and I need a method to encrypt the main "secret algorithm". In my system each OTP has a pair named "solution" and it is also changing like the OTP. I need to store the algorithm securely.

I tried to store pre-generated pairs with hashed solution, but it was too slow and has many disadvantages.

There is no password in the system.

Has anybody a better idea?

---

Example

Code given to the user: `29483758272894739584832`

```
       |
       |
       ˇ
secret operation
       |
       ˇ
```

Solution: `235`

Comment: Do you mean [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) instead of "encrypt"?  If no, then your problem is independent of the fact that what you are trying to encrypt is a OTP authentication algorithm.

Comment: I need to recover the stored information when generating the next OTP. You're right, the method is not depends on the problem, but I need to extract somehow the secret key from the codetable and solution or the algorithm and that is my exact question.